# Extracting polygons from closed lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I have a line layer having lakes and rivers. I would like to extract only the lakes (which are closed curves) from the layer.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do the following:

1. Use the **v.clean** algorithm which you can find in:

   ```
    Processing Toolbox > GRASS commands > GRASS GIS 7 commands > Vector (v.*) > v.clean
   ```
2. Select the *rmdangle* tool.
3. Enter a threshold less than 0 (e.g. `-0.1`). The description mentions:

   > "With thresh < 0, only closed loops and lines connecting loops will remain."
4. Use the **Lines to polygons** tool which you can find in the menubar:

   ```
    Vector > Geometry Tools > Lines to polygons
   ```

---

Example:

Simple line layer:

[image: Line layer]

Using **v.clean** with the following parameters:

[image: v.clean]

Output:

[image: Output]

Using **Lines to polygons** to get final result:

[image: Result]

Comment: When I try doing vclean, it shows an error:

Comment: `ERROR: Sorry is not a valid option 
ERROR: Sorry is not a valid option 
ERROR: Sorry is not a valid option 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>g.region -a n=59.169201 s=48.054169 e=-90.0282810742 w=-117.085907 res=100 
ERROR: Illegal latitude for North 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>v.clean input=tmp1497028525634 tool=rmdangle threshold="-0.1" output=output367770ddec814c7a8e92e5a036383edf error=error367770ddec814c7a8e92e5a036383edf --overwrite 
ERROR: Vector map not found`

Comment: @KuljeetKeshav - Perhaps your line layer contains errors. You could try running the **Check validity** from the menubar: `Vector > Geometry Tools > Check validity`. If so then you can try cleaning this up using another tool from **v.clean** or the **Geometry Checker** plugin.